# Get current display count from Ngx-Datatable

Tags: angular, datatable

I have been using swimlane/ngx-datatbles with angular5. Want to add a new footer that has the current displayCount.
https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable

Here is what I want in the footer:
Showing 10 of 25 total

Hoping the code is something like this

`Showing {{displayCount}} of {{rowCount.toLocaleString()}} total`

There are examples here of custom footers:

```
    <ngx-datatable-footer>
      <ng-template ngx-datatable-footer-template let-rowCount="rowCount" let-pageSize="pageSize" let-selectedCount="selectedCount"
        let-curPage="curPage" let-offset="offset" let-isVisible="isVisible">
        <div style="margin: 10px">
          <select class="form-control" style="width: 150px; font-size: 14px" (change)="onLimitChange($event.target.value)">
            <option *ngFor="let option of pageLimitOptions" [value]="option.value" [selected]="option.value == pageSize">
              {{ option.value }} per page
            </option>
          </select>
        </div>
        Showing {{displayCount}} of {{rowCount.toLocaleString()}} total
        <datatable-pager [pagerLeftArrowIcon]="'datatable-icon-left'" [pagerRightArrowIcon]="'datatable-icon-right'" [pagerPreviousIcon]="'datatable-icon-prev'"
          [pagerNextIcon]="'datatable-icon-skip'" [page]="curPage" [size]="pageSize" [count]="rowCount" [hidden]="false"
          (change)="table.onFooterPage($event)">
        </datatable-pager>
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-footer>
```

Other footer examples: https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/739

However I do not see a way to get a display count. 
Is there any way to do this in its latest/any version?

Answer (score 2):

```
   <ngx-datatable-footer>
      <ng-template 
        ngx-datatable-footer-template 
        let-rowCount="rowCount"
        let-pageSize="pageSize"
        let-selectedCount="selectedCount"
        let-curPage="curPage"
        let-offset="offset">
        <div style="padding: 5px 10px">
          <div>
            Showing {{(offset * pageSize)+1}} to {{(rowCount> 
              (curPage*pageSize))?(curPage*pageSize):(rowCount)}} of 
              {{(rowCount)}} records.
          </div>
        </div>
        <datatable-pager
        [pagerLeftArrowIcon]="'datatable-icon-left'"
        [pagerRightArrowIcon]="'datatable-icon-right'"
        [pagerPreviousIcon]="'datatable-icon-prev'"
        [pagerNextIcon]="'datatable-icon-skip'"
        [page]="curPage"
        [size]="pageSize"
        [count]="rowCount"
        [hidden]="!((rowCount / pageSize) > 1)"
        (change)="table.onFooterPage($event)">
         </datatable-pager>
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-footer>
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation with your code in answer.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks. @pratik-sankhe

Answer (score 0):

```
Here we go tableRef given with # : i.e. #myTable
and check count of records for table: i.e data which is type [].
     <ngx-datatable-footer>
    <ng-template
      ngx-datatable-footer-template
      let-rowCount="rowCount"
      let-pageSize="pageSize"
      let-selectedCount="selectedCount"
      let-curPage="curPage"
      let-offset="offset"
      let-isVisible="isVisible">
      <div class="page-count" *ngIf="data && data.length > 0">
        {{'showing'|translate}} {{(offset * pageSize)+1}} {{'to'|translate}} {{(rowCount>
        (curPage*pageSize))?(curPage*pageSize):(rowCount)}}{{'of'|translate}}
        {{(totalCount)}} {{'records'|translate}}
      </div>
      <datatable-pager
        [pagerLeftArrowIcon]="'fa fa-chevron-left'"
        [pagerRightArrowIcon]="'fa fa-chevron-right'"
        [pagerPreviousIcon]="'fa fa-step-backward'"
        [pagerNextIcon]="'fa fa-step-forward'"
        [page]="curPage"
        [size]="pageSize"
        [count]="rowCount"
        [hidden]="!((rowCount / pageSize) > 1)"
        (change)="myTable.onFooterPage($event)"
      >
      </datatable-pager>
    </ng-template>
  </ngx-datatable-footer>
```